# Maximize the minimum score

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a grid of dimensions `A*B` with values between 1-9, find a sequence of `B` numbers that maximizes the minimum number of values matched when compared with `A` rows.

Describe the certain steps you would take to maximize the minimum score.

**Example**:

**Grid Dimension**

`A` = 5 , `B` = 10

**Grid Values**

```
9 3 9 2 9 9 4 5 7 6
6 3 4 2 8 5 7 5 9 2
4 9 5 8 3 7 3 2 7 6
7 5 8 9 9 4 7 3 3 7
2 6 8 3 2 4 5 4 2 2
```

**Possible Answer**

```
6 3 8 2 9 4 7 5 7 4
```

**Score Calculation**

This answer scores

5 when compared with Row 1

5 when compared with Row 2

1 when compared with Row 3

4 when compared with Row 4

2 when compared with Row 5

**And thus the minimal score *for this answer* is 1.**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @al-dev I've found the mode of each column. I've also tried some variants, like if there are bi or tri modal values, then calculating the mean of the all the modes.

Answer (score -1):

I would go for a local hill-climbing approach that you can complement with a randomization to avoid local minima. Something like:

```
1. Generate a random starting solution S
2. Compute its score score(S, row) for each row. We'll call min_score(S) the minimum score among all rows for S.
3. Attempt to improve the solution with:
  For each digit i (1..B) in S:
    If i belongs to a row such that score(S, row) > (min_score(S) + 1) then:
      Change i to be the digit of a row with min_score(S). If there was only one row with min_score(S), then min_score(S) has improved by 1
      Update the scores of all the rows.
  If min_score(S) hasn't improved for more than N iterations of 3, go back to 1 and start with a new random solution.
```